# Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR. TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

When I run build after npm install I am getting this error. But if I install grunt globally and run `grunt build` it passes the task.

This is package.json

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-text-replace": "^0.3.12",
    "js-yaml": "3.2.*",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "node -e \"require('grunt').tasks(['build']);\""
  }
  ...
}
```

I am getting the below error when I run `npm run build`

```
Loading "jshint.js" tasks...ERROR
>> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string
Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! superapp@1.0.0 build: `node -e "require('grunt').tasks(['build']);"`
npm ERR! Exit status 3
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the superapp@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mac/.npm/_logs/2018-01-12T04_27_38_104Z-debug.log
```

My gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  grunt.initConfig({
   ...
  });

  // Register Task Aliases
  grunt.registerTask('styles', ['sass', 'replace']);
  grunt.registerTask('base', ['jshint', 'styles']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['base', 'yaml']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['base', 'watch']);

};
```

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jshint/issues/277

Comment: Can you provide all the code in gruntfile.js?

Comment: When I included `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);` the error occurred. When I replace to `require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt, {pattern: ['grunt-*', '@*/grunt-*', "!grunt-contrib-jshint"]});` this, error gone.